# Can't print JSON data into Dart Objects - "Instance of 'Object'"

Tags: json, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Please help!
Consider me a newbie of flutter. I 'm trying to convert my JSON data into dart objects and then want to save it to Firestore.

I want to see the details of NGO not just Instance. What should I do? I think I have made all classes accurate. There's some problem in my this function might be:

```
  Future<void>  _NgoDetail() async {
    String jsonString = await _loadANgoAsset();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    var rest = jsonResponse[0] as List;
    List list=[];
    list= rest.map<NGO>((json) => NGO.fromJson(json)).toList();
   debugPrint(list.toString());
  }
```

OUTPUT on terminal is:

```
Instance of 'NGO', Instance of 'NGO', Instance of 'NGO', Instance of 'NGO', Instance of 'NGO'
```

However:
This is my NGO class:

```
class NGO {
  String name;
  String id;
  RegDetails regDetails;
  contactDetails ContactDetails;
  Members members;
  WorkingSectors workingSectors;
  NGO({this.members,this.regDetails,this.name,this.workingSectors,this.ContactDetails,this.id,});
 factory NGO.fromjson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
   return  NGO(
     id: json["id"],
     name:json['name'],
     regDetails: RegDetails.fromJson(json['regDetails']),
     ContactDetails: contactDetails.fromJson(json['ContactDetails']),
     members: Members.fromJson(json['members']),
     workingSectors: WorkingSectors.fromJson(json['workingSectors'])
   );
 }

/*    @required this.DateOfReg,
    this.NGOType,
    this.RegisteredWith,
    this.FCRA,
    this.PAN,
    this.persons,
    this.RegAddress,
    this.RegDistrict,
    this.RegState,
    this.UniqueID,
    this.WorkSectors});*/

}
```

This is my JSON struct:

```
[
[
{
"nos": 0,
"name": "A S MUSIC AND DANCE A CULTURAL ORGANIZATION",
"unique_id": "AN/2020/0259067",
"reg_details": [
{
"registered_with": "Registrar of Societies"
},
{
"type_of_ngo": "Registered Societies (Non-Government)"
},
{
"registration_no": "1534"
},
{
"copy_of_registration_certificate": "Available"
},
{
"copy_of_pan_card": "Available"
},
{
"act_name": "Registration Act,1860"
},
{
"city_of_registration": "Port Blair"
},
{
"state_of_registration": "ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS"
},
{
"date_of_registration": "25-05-2016"
}
],
"members": [
{
"name": "Shamsuddin",
"designation": "President",
"pan": "Available",
"aadhaar": "Available"
},
{
"name": "Sheikh Mohammed",
"designation": "Secretary",
"pan": "Available",
"aadhaar": "Available"
},
{
"name": "Mahatab Jabeen",
"designation": "Treasurer",
"pan": "Available",
"aadhaar": "Available"
}
],
"sector": [
{
"key_issues": "Not Available"
},
{
"operational_area_states": "Not Available"
},
{
"operational_area_district": "Not Available"
}
],
"contact_details": [
{
"address": "AS Music And Dance A Cultural Organization, 8,Air Lane Delanipur Port Blair, South Andaman.744102"
},
{
"city": "Port Blair"
},
{
"state": "ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS"
},
{
"telephone": "Not Available"
},
{
"mobile_no": "9933273585"
},
{
"website_url": "Not Available"
},
{
"e_mail": "asmusicanddancepb(at)gmail[dot]com"
}
]
},
{
"nos": 1,
"name": "AdityaNatyaAcademy",
"unique_id": "AN/2017/0161456",
"reg_details": [],
"members": [
{
"name": "ASHUTOSH KARMAKAR",
"designation": "President",
"pan": "Available",
"aadhaar": "Available"
},
{
"name": "KAVERI DEBSHARMA",
"designation": "Member",
"pan": "Available",
"aadhaar": "Available"
},
{
"name": "SATYAJIT BAIN",
"designation": "Asisstant Secretary",
"pan": "Available",
"aadhaar": "Available"
}
],
```

And these are my other classes for JSON parsing purpose in NGO:

```
class RegDetails{
  String registration_no;
  String type_of_ngo;
  String registered_with;
  String copy_of_pan_card;
  String date_of_registration;
  String city_of_registration;
  String state_of_registration;
  String FCRA;
  RegDetails({this.FCRA='Not Available',this.city_of_registration,this.copy_of_pan_card,this.date_of_registration,this.registered_with,this.registration_no,this.state_of_registration,this.type_of_ngo});
  factory RegDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return RegDetails(
      registration_no: json['registered_no'],
      type_of_ngo: json['type_of_ngo'],
      registered_with: json['registered_with'],
      copy_of_pan_card: json['copy_of_pan_card'],
      date_of_registration: json['date_of_registeration'],
      city_of_registration: json['city_of_registeration'],
      state_of_registration: json['state_of_registeration'],
    );
  }
}
class contactDetails{
  String address;
  String city;
  String state;
  String telephone;
  String mobile_no;
  String website_url;
  String e_mail;
  contactDetails({this.address,this.city,this.e_mail,this.mobile_no,this.state,this.telephone,this.website_url});
  factory contactDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return contactDetails(
      address: json["address"],
      city: json["city"],
      state: json["state"],
      telephone: json["telephone"],
      mobile_no: json["mobile_no"],
      website_url: json["website_url"],
      e_mail: json["e_mail"]


    );
  }
}
class Members{
  String name;
  String designation;
  String pan;
  String adhaar;
  Members({this.name,this.designation,this.pan,this.adhaar});
  factory Members.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Members(
      name: json["name"],
      designation: json["designation"],
      pan:json["pan"],
      adhaar:json["adhaar"]
    );
  }

}
class WorkingSectors{
  String operational_area_states;
  String key_issues;
  String operational_area_district;
  WorkingSectors({this.key_issues,this.operational_area_district,this.operational_area_states});
  factory WorkingSectors.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
   return WorkingSectors(
       operational_area_states: json["operational_area_states"],
       key_issues: json["key_issues"],
       operational_area_district:json["operational_area_district"]
   );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Getting `instanceOf` is great news. It means that you are only one step away from accessing property you need from the object!

  Just change

  ```
  debugPrint(list.toString());
  ```

  To this:

  ```
  debugPrint(list[0].name); // This will print the name of the NGO at index[0] in your list.
  ```
- When you say `print(List<Object>)`, it will print the objects of that list.

  For example, if your list was `List _numbers = [1,2,3];` and then `print(_numbers)` => it'll result in `1 2 3`.
- In your case, `list` is a `List<NGO> list`, when you `debugPrint(list)`, you get the result of what you are seeing now:

  ```
  Instance of 'NGO', Instance of 'NGO', Instance of 'NGO', Instance of 'NGO', Instance of 'NGO'
  ```

Again, in response to this:

> There's some problem in my this function might be:

When you see `Instance of "Object"`, don't panic, but get excited, you are very close!

Comment: This is working fine `debugPrint(list[0].name);`. But why not this: `debugPrint(list[0].regDetails[8].date_of_registration);` regDetails is also an instance that contains list of objects , why it couldn't be printed?

Comment: Do you have 9 objects in `regDetails`? What is the output of what you posted? `regDetails` is not a list, but this `debugPrint(list[0].regDetails.date_of_registration);` will work.

Comment: This `debugPrint(list[0].regDetails.date_of_registration);` doesn't work.It says: `Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`.

Comment: This means that it's not being parsed correctly. This is how it should be accessed: `debugPrint(list[0].regDetails[8]['date_of_registration']`, because regDetails is a map, not alist, you access it using a `key` not index. Try it and report back

Comment: This specific line is causing issue. `regDetails: RegDetails.fromJson(json['regDetails']),` in  factory NGO.fromJson function. Am I not declaring it right?

Comment: You are not returning it right in your regdetails class, you are passing it a list of maps, not a map. This is different question than your original post. Kindly consider marking this as an answer to your question, and figuring our how to iterate of alist of maps, is for another post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see details of your object, I think you can try something like this.

```
debugPrint(list.map((e) =>jsonEncode(e)).toString());
```